# How to prove $\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I algebraically prove that the equation

$$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

is true for all $x$? I know I can draw a right-angled triangle to do this, but can I show this algebraically? Thanks.

Comment: It's true for $x > 0$ only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove it, either algebraically or analytically, because it's false:
$$
\arctan(-1)+\arctan\Bigl(\frac{1}{-1}\Bigr)=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

It's a common misunderstanding arguing, from the fact a function has zero derivative at each point of its domain, that the function is constant. But what you can say is that it is “constant on each interval contained in its domain”.

Since the domain of $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, all you can say is that the function is constant on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$.

Let $x>0$ and consider $\alpha=\arctan(1/x)$. Then
$$
\tan\alpha=\frac{1}{x}
$$
so $x=\cot\alpha=\tan(\pi/2-\alpha)$. Thus
$$
\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha+\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Note that the hypothesis $x>0$ has been used for deducing from $x=\tan(\pi/2-\alpha)$ that $\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\alpha$.

Now just use the fact that $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$ to do the case $x<0$ and find that
$$
\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if $x>0$}\\[6px]
-\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Note.** I find the notation $\tan^{-1}$ abusive, because the tangent function has no inverse, so I stick with $\arctan x$, that denotes the inverse function of a particular branch of the tangent.

Comment: Yes, that resolves the errors in my now-deleted answer.

Comment: That was a very informative answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could prove your result  as follows also:
Note that : $\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}1/x -\pi$, when $x\lt0$...(A) and is equal to $\tan^{-1}1/x$ when $x\gt0$..(B)

PROOF:I am proving for $x$ being negative.For +ve $x$ it's quite easy to prove.

Suppose, $y=-z$, ($z$ is positive ), hence  $\cot^{-1}(y)=\cot^{-1}(-z)=\pi -\cot^{-1}(z)$ Now you might be knowing :$\cot^{-1}(z)=\tan^{-1}(1/z)$ for positive $z$, hence $\cot^{-1}(-z)=\pi - \tan^{-1}(1/z)$. Now substitue $z=-y$, then use $\tan^{-1}(-1/y)=-\tan^{-1}(1/y)$ and you get the result.

Now you may argue: why $\cot^{-1}(-z)=\pi-\cot^{-1}z$?

Well, it's because :Let $z=\cot\theta$, $0<\theta<\pi$[principal branch of $\cot$]. So $-z=\cot(\pi-\theta)$ , Note that $\pi- \theta$ is also in between $0$ and $\pi$. So you can define $\cot^{-1}(-z)$, which in this case will be: $\pi -\theta$, Now put $\theta=\cot^{-1}(z)$, Hence proved.

So coming to: $\tan^{-1}x +\tan^{-1}1/x=I$, say

So $I=\tan^{-1}x +\cot^{-1}x=\pi/2$, when $x\gt0$ [by (B)]

And $I=\tan^{-1}x +\cot^{-1}x-\pi=\pi/2-\pi=-\pi/2$, when $x \lt0$ [by (A)]