# double integral of two Gaussians and complex poles

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, error-function

Recently encountered an integral:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{ (x_1+x_2) e^{-i(x_1+x_2)k} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_1-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2} -\frac{(x_2-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) }{(x_1+x_2-\alpha-\beta)(x_1-\gamma)(x_2-\delta)} d x_1 d x_2,$$
where $k, \sigma$ are Real, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are complex, but their imaginary parts are negative.

I have tried to change variables to $x_+=x_1+x_2, x_-=x_1-x_2$, it results:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x_+ e^{-ix_+k} \exp\left( - \frac{x_-^2}{4 \sigma^2} - \frac{(x_+-2x_0)^2}{4 \sigma^2} \right) }{(x_+-\alpha-\beta)(x_++x_--\gamma)(x_+-x_--\delta)} 2 d x_+ d x_-$$.

But did not help much. It seems impossible to factorize the integrand into $f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)$ because of $x_1+x_2$.

What I know is that the integral of a Gaussian with a complex pole can be reduced to complex valued error function. For exmaple, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}}{x-\alpha}dx = - i \pi w \left( -\frac{\alpha}{\sigma} \right)$, where $w(z)$ is Faddeeva/Kramp function, here $\text{Im}(\alpha)<0$, and $\sigma$ is real, as before.

Even if I somehow can get rid of one of the integral, the second one will contain Gaussian, error function, and pole(s). What are the chances to have an answer for this integral in terms of special functions?

**UPDATE:**
After expanding into the minimal denominators with $x_1, x_2$, I realized that the only part I can not compute has the following form:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{w\left( \eta + \xi  x_2 \right) e^{-\frac{(x_2 - \nu )^2}{2 \sigma^2}} }{(x_2 - \mu)} d x_2 $$,
where $w(z)$ is Faddeeva function, $\nu, \eta, \nu, \mu$ are complex, while $\sigma$ is real.

Comment: One can not use contour integration with infinite semicircles in integrals containing Gaussians - it diverges at both imaginary infinities