# Integrating a product of exponential and complementary error function in a communication scenario.

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, error-function

While studying the communication signal processing, it was proved that the following integrals play an important role in the block error rate approximation of the MPSK signals:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^{2}+bx)\mathrm{erfc}(x)dx，
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\exp(-ax^{2}+bx)\mathrm{erfc}(x)dx，
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{erfc}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$ is the complementary error function.

It is a famous result that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^{2}+bx)\mathrm{erfc}(x)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\exp({\frac{b^{2}}{4a}})\mathrm{erfc}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a(a+1)}})$$
And I use mathematica to calculte the above two integrals, it gives me the following results while I could not understand how to get them through some substuition or some integral skills?
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^{2}+bx)\mathrm{erfc}(x)dx=\frac{\mathrm{erfc}(2\sqrt{a}+be^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}\sqrt{\pi}(1+\mathrm{erf}(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}})))}{4a^{3/2}},
\end{equation}
if
$$Re[a]=0 \quad \& \quad Re[b]<0 \quad or \quad Re[a]>0,$$
where $Re[\cdot]$ is the real part of a real number.
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\exp(-ax^{2}+bx)\mathrm{erfc}(x)dx=\frac{\mathrm{erfc}(-2\sqrt{a}+be^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{erfc}(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}))}{4a^{3/2}},
\end{equation}
provided that
$$Re[a]=0 \quad \& \quad Re[b]>0 \quad or \quad Re[a]>0.$$

I would be extremely grateful if anyone could give me some advice.
Have a nice and pleasure day!

@ Przemo  If it is convenient for you to give me some slight suggestions about how to calculate, thanks a lot for your generous help ~

Comment: @Robert Lee, I'm sorry to bother you that if you could give me some advice of how to deal with the above integrals related to the erfc function~ Thanks a lot ! Have a nice day, Liu !

Comment: @Angelo, I'm sorry to bother you that if you could give me some suggestions of how to deal with the above integrals related to the erfc function ? Thanks a lot for your help ! Have a nice day, Liu !

Comment: @Przemo, I'm sorry to take up some of your time and I'm sorry to bother you that if you could give me some advice of how to prove the above equality related to the complementary error function~ Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @David P, David, I'm sorry to bother you that whether you could give some suggestions of how to deal with the above integrals. Maybe I could use some substuition ? I have got stuck of these integrals for about a week. Thanks a lot for your help ! Best regards to you !

Comment: It seems that the results given by mathematica are not really the true results of the above integrals? I hope that if anyone could help me to calculate the above integrals. Best regrads!

Comment: Hi, Robert Lee, @Robert Lee, I'm sorry to bother you that if you have some ideas about the above questions which is similar to the question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316676/gaussian-integral-with-error-function/4317177#4317177      Thanks a lot ! Best regards !