# Finding integer solutions to an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, integers

The question is what are the integer solutions for $x$ and $y$ which satisfy this equation:
$$4^x = y^2+15$$
What I did was sketch the graph of $y = 4^x$ and the graph of $x = y^2 + 15$ and since these graphs don't intersect, there are no solutions to the equation.
My understanding is obviously wrong because at least 1 solution is $x = 2, y = 1$, but can someone help me understand why I am wrong.

Comment: Take any of the graphs, say $y=4^x$ for an example.  Why do you think a solution to $4^x=y^2+15$ should be on this graph?  For instance $(x,y)=(2, -1)$ is a solution to the original equation, can it be on any of your graphs?

Comment: If you want a graphical approach (the algebraic one solves it, the graph can at best illustrate), then you could graph $\log_4(x^2+15)$ and look where it can be an integer - i.e. you are looking for lattice points on that graph, like so: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+Log%5B4%2C+x%5E2%2B15%5D%2C+0%3Cx%3C10%2C+grid

Answer (score 3):

One approach is noticing that $4^x = \left(2^x \right)^2$ to rewrite the equation as
$$
\left(2^x +y\right)\left(2^x -y\right) = 15
$$
If both $x$ and $y$ are integers, then so are $2^x \pm y$, so they must be divisors of $15$. Furthermore, since $(2^x+y) +(2^x -y) = 2^{x+1} >0$ then both pairs of divisors must be positive to add up to a positive number (since the alternative is both being negative because their product is postive).  The  full list of positive divisors of $15$ is $\left\{1,  3, 5,  15 \right\}$, so checking each of the two pairs that multiply to $15$ and equating one of each pair to one of $2^x \pm y$, gives the complete list of solutions
$$
(x,y) \in \{(3,7), (2,1), (2,-1), (3,-7)\}
$$

Comment: Hi, Robert, it's a nice answer and I'm sorry to bother you that if you could give me some advice about how to deal with the following integrals corresponds to the complementary error function ? Thanks a lot for your help ! Best regards ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727014/integrating-a-product-of-exponential-and-complementary-error-function-in-a-commu

Answer (score 0):

Graphing functions tells us when two same variables of functions are equal. In order to find x and y which satisfies the given the equation, we must know for what value this equation has x and y as integers. $4^x$ is exponential function of x and it has values always greater than zero for $x\in$[-R,R].
So for $4^x$ less than 15, we have y as a complex number. So, 4^x must be greater than 15 for real y. For solution to be integer, 4^x has to be a integer. It can be seen explicity that if $x=n$ or $x=n+\frac{1}{2}$ and $n\geq2$ where $n\in{N}$, then y is integer which satify the equation. For x and y to be integers, ($x\in{N}$ and $x\geq2$).